# Making Register Plus Redux work with Nextend Google Connect

Tags: facebook, wordpress, plugins, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to make two popular WordPress plug-ins work well together.  Hopefully this question isn't too specific to my setup -- I think enough people use these plug-ins to make it a common issue.

I'm using Register Plus Redex (RPR) to require user registration to be accepted (by admin) before a user can log-in.  Alone, this works fine.

I'm also using Nextend Google Connect (NGC) to allow users to log-in with Google.  Those also need to be approved before they can log-in.

When NGC creates a new user in the database, it correctly has the "not activated" flag set.  However, the user is still logged in.  This allows them to see some blog pages that are protected by "Members Only" (another plug-in).  I could maybe update Members Only or other areas to avoid this, but I would rather these users see the same behavior a normal user would see, one that just logs in with user/password, not Google.  They get a nice "Your account has not been activated yet" message.

RPR has this code to authenticate, I think I need to use it from NGC some way:

```
    public /*.object.*/ function rpr_authenticate( /*.object.*/ $user, /*.string.*/ $username, /*.string.*/ $password) {
        if ( !empty($user) && !is_wp_error( $user ) ) {
            if ( NULL !== get_role( 'rpr_unverified' ) && in_array( 'rpr_unverified', $user->roles ) ) {
                return null;
            }
        }
        return $user;
    }
```

I think this is the section of NGC code I need to modify:

```
    $secure_cookie = is_ssl();
    $secure_cookie = apply_filters('secure_signon_cookie', $secure_cookie, array());
    global $auth_secure_cookie; // XXX ugly hack to pass this to wp_authenticate_cookie

    $auth_secure_cookie = $secure_cookie;
    wp_set_auth_cookie($ID, true, $secure_cookie);
    $user_info = get_userdata($ID);
    do_action('wp_login', $user_info->user_login, $user_info);
    do_action('nextend_google_user_logged_in', $ID, $u, $oauth2);
    update_user_meta($ID, 'google_profile_picture', 'https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/' . $u['id']);
```

The NGC code uses what I think is a "hacked" method of log-in.  It doesn't use any of the methods I have seen recommended online, like the new `wp_signon` or older `wp_login` functions.

Is what I'm trying to do a major project?  If so, is there another combination of plug-ins (or a single one) that will handle the following:

1. Require users to be logged in to see any pages (what Members Only does)
2. Require admin to moderate/approve new users (what RPR does)
3. Support log-in via Facebook, Twitter, and Google (what the Nextend Connect plug-ins do)

**Update:**

I changed the NGC code to this, and now it doesn't log the user in, but it just leaves them on the log-in page with no error message.  I'm not sure how I can add an error message to the default log-in page, everything I find online is related to custom log-in pages.

```
      if ($ID) { // Login

        $user_info = get_userdata($ID);
            if ( !empty($user_info) && !is_wp_error( $user_info ) ) {
                if ( NULL !== get_role( 'rpr_unverified' ) && in_array( 'rpr_unverified', $user_info->roles ) ) {
// TODO - How to add error message to log-in page?
                    return;
                }
            }

        $secure_cookie = is_ssl();
        $secure_cookie = apply_filters('secure_signon_cookie', $secure_cookie, array());
        global $auth_secure_cookie; // XXX ugly hack to pass this to wp_authenticate_cookie

        $auth_secure_cookie = $secure_cookie;
        wp_set_auth_cookie($ID, true, $secure_cookie);
//
        do_action('wp_login', $user_info->user_login, $user_info);
        do_action('nextend_google_user_logged_in', $ID, $u, $oauth2);
        update_user_meta($ID, 'google_profile_picture', 'https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/' . $u['id']);
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a better way to do this, one that will not be undone anytime I update the plug-in, but for now this works for me.

I updated nextend-google-connect.php, part of the Nextend Google Connect plug-in, and changed the Login code (starting around line 230 depending on your version) to this:

```
  if ($ID) { // Login

    $user_info = get_userdata($ID);
        if ( !empty($user_info) && !is_wp_error( $user_info ) ) {
            if ( NULL !== get_role( 'rpr_unverified' ) && in_array( 'rpr_unverified', $user_info->roles ) ) {
                wp_redirect('wp-login.php?checkemail=registered');
                exit;
            }
        }

    $secure_cookie = is_ssl();
    $secure_cookie = apply_filters('secure_signon_cookie', $secure_cookie, array());
    global $auth_secure_cookie; // XXX ugly hack to pass this to wp_authenticate_cookie

    $auth_secure_cookie = $secure_cookie;
    wp_set_auth_cookie($ID, true, $secure_cookie);

    do_action('wp_login', $user_info->user_login, $user_info);
    do_action('nextend_google_user_logged_in', $ID, $u, $oauth2);
    update_user_meta($ID, 'google_profile_picture', 'https://profiles.google.com/s2/photos/profile/' . $u['id']);
  }
```

By redirecting to that special URL, the Redux plug-in already has code to display a nice message to the user letting them know the admin needs to verify the account.